# How does the detection mark for Pyke's Ghostwater Dive ability work?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am playing Pyke, a champion in League of Legends. I need some clarity on one of his abilities called Ghostwater Dive. Here is a link to show it: [Pkye ghostwater dive](https://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/ability/ghostwater-dive-883). Basically, the spell makes you invisible to enemies in a certain range and makes you move faster. Now the one thing that has me confused is something that is not said, when Pyke uses this the enemies close by get a mark around their bodies that tells them Pyke is invisible. I know this is a thing but it does not show it in the ability description. So my questions are:

**1. What is the range of the mark that Pyke puts out?**

**2. If there is a range if I start outside the range then go into the range will the mark still appear on the enemies?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyke's Ghostwater Dive ability has two radiuses around him. The first is quite small at 600 units, and any enemies within this range will be able to see Pyke despite him being camouflaged. The second is an unnamed radius that, for simplicity's sake, I'll refer to as a "notification radius." Enemies within this notification radius will have the mark placed around them and will hear music depending upon how close to Pyke's ultimate, Death from Below's execute threshold they are.

> What is the range of the mark that Pyke puts out?

No wiki page actually documents the range at which Pyke will display this mark around enemies, but from personal testing I've found that the distance is the same distance at which Rengar's R, Thrill of the Hunt will mark the closest enemy. [Rengar's wiki](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Rengar/LoL) indicates that the sensing range is 1600 units, and after a bunch of measurement, I found that Pyke's is exactly the same at **1600 units**.

> If I start outside the range then go into the range will the mark still appear on the enemies?

Yes. If you start at a distance of greater than 1600 units from an enemy champion and use Ghostwater Dive, the enemy champion will not have a mark around them. While still under the effect of Ghostwater Dive, if you move within 1600 units of that same enemy champion, they will then see the mark around them. The same applies if you then move outside of the 1600 unit distance, as the mark will disappear.